# When and where is used the getAllowedMethods method?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, shipment-tracking

I'm implementing a custom carrier and did notice the `getAllowedMethods` method defined at `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`. I know that it returns an array with the allowed methods but I can't yet figure out in which scenario this method is used/called.

Also, what's the format that the data in the array should have? What does the keys are and what does the values represent?

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating any shipping method, you have to implement this interface `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`

All the existing shipping methods have implemented this interface. Some of the classes are listed below.

```
 - Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate
 - Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Pickup
 - Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping
```

If you check all these classes you will easily grab the idea that about keys and values of the array returned by `getAllowedMethods()`

Every shipping method should have a unique code (unique string). And these codes are the keys of the array and names of relevant shipping methods are the values.

See the example below. In here shipping method code is `freeshipping`. And value will be shipping method name whatever you set in the admin panel.

```
 /**
     * Get allowed shipping methods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('freeshipping' => $this->getConfigData('name'));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sukeshini, I understand that this method is required for a new carrier to work, also I noticed that the carriers under Mage_Usa use this method. 
What I also would like to know is at which moment does this method is called? For example, is it called when the user enters the checkout page? Or is it called when a new tracking number is saved?

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 1.x.
You can see result of `getAllowedMethods()` here:

1. **AdminPanel -> Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rule -> Conditions -> Add**
2. Add there new rule based on "**Shipping method**"
3. Press on **...**

Voila!

There are you methods in the dropdown! (If you set up your shipping module correctly).